# ez_setp.py: how to download the package to install for future install from disk?

Tags: python, installation

I'm using `ez_setup.py` to install `pysal` for QGis, by using the command:

```
easy_install pysal
```

(I followed the following post: http://anitagraser.com/2014/07/13/installing-pysal-for-osgeo4w/)

I have to do those installs in countries where Internet may not be available. 
So I would like to use `ez_setup.py` to get the package and save it on a drive, and once at destination, run ez_setup.py to install the package from the file. 
How can I do that?

Comment: `ez_setup.py` is used only to install setuptool. When you execute `ez_setup.py` it will create a easy_install.exe and this exe is used to install the other packages. Like path_to/easy_install matlab

Comment: you can download any module package from Pypi site `https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=index` and use easy_install to install that module in future.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Install PySAL](http://pysal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/users/installation.html): PySAL is a pure Python module which needs only that [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPY](http://www.scipy.org/) are available and they are installed by default in QGIS (Standalone version, OSGeo4W version).

Therefore, use the basic operation of [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html):

1) place PySAL-....tar.gz on a USB stick  ([PySAL 1.10.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySAL/1.10.0) for example)
2) unzip it in the destination PC
3) cd into the unzipped directory (PySAL-...)
4) the installation instruction are in the INSTALL.txt
5) type in /.../python setup.py install (the Python version of QGIS)